Replace the Atmega16U2 on the ArduinoMega2560 with Arduino ISP programmer?
I'm working on a custom ArduinoMega2560 and I was wondering if I could replace the 16U2 with the Arduino ISP https://docs.arduino.cc/retired/boards/arduino-isp/ (it's cheaper and simpler).
Does this module allow me to program the Atmega2560 and connect it to the computer like the 16U2 does?

I think there is a cheaper option using the same programmer that is needed for the Arduino Pro Mini. Either add a 6 pin header on your custom 2560 board or copy the complete programmer schematic design with a common VCP driver.
The FT232 will cost a bit more than the CH340 virtual comm port from Aliexpress. Chinese Arduino Nano clone boards also use a CH340 for programming.

On lcsc.com the CH340C costs only $0.47

This would require an installed bootloader on the custom ArduinoMega2560, which is not the case.

The Arduino IDE has a "program bootloader" option. So the first time the mega2560 is programmed, he would need an arduino isp programmer. possibly the one that @Tristan mentioned. In that case the board, specifically the 2560, needs a 6pin isp header. It would be the cheap option but more work.

@hennep - Hi, Thanks for answering. However, where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the answer & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). (Doesn't apply here but if the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition.) TY

Thanks @SamGibson, I didn't notice that the URL to the image above had changed. It showed the original site when I posted it. The image came from https://www.electroinvention.co.in/program-arduino-pro-mini-ft232rl/ and it was posted there by Gaurav Pant. I just copied an image link from google images :-)

To program the 2560, yes, the arduino ISP will work. In fact, other than those intended for hobbyists and development boards intended to get you up from zero quickly, most boards won't include an on board programmer, since it's something you only use once. The MCU and the firmware you program into it will take over after that. In cases where you expect to need to reprogram, you can use a bootloader which can be written using the ICSP, and that will let you update the program through uart/usb after that, instead of needing ICSP.
If cost is a crucial determining factor to you, you may want to look for the USBASP. That's a similar programmer which has been around long enough for there to be numerous extremely low cost clones at nearly throwaway prices.
Communication though won't be possible with these programmers. ICSP uses only the ICSP pins and does nothing with the UART pins. Some programmers also do include a USB-UART channel and an alternate connector for UART, but in my experience that only serves to confuse matters most of the time. You may want to add an FT232 or CH340 on your 2560 board to provide UART to USB conversion if you want USB connectivity on the final board, as is normally the case.  There are many small dongles available with those ICs as well, if you only want to communicate during development. These, also have been around long enough for crappy but otherwise functional clones and knockoffs to be easily available.
